# Bootstrap Popover not shows when dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding a popover to my when dropdown menu is changed

```
$('#boarding').on('change',function(){
    var drl="sometext";
    txt='<td><a style="color:#333;" href="#" title="Dropping points" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="'+drl+'">Newitem</a></td>';
 $('#result').html(txt);
});
```

Also i am adding this inside `document.ready`

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html:true,trigger: "hover"});
```

When i hover the mouse on it dosen't show the popover,but the text is present in `data-content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move your `.popover()` call inside the `change` event listener:

```
$('#boarding').on('change',function(){
  var drl="sometext";
  txt='<td><a style="color:#333;" href="#" title="Dropping points" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="'+drl+'">Newitem</a></td>';
  $('#result').html(txt);
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html:true,trigger: "hover"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the popover after you have added it:

```
$("a[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
```

Add similar call after `$('#result').html(txt);`.